# Finding the location of the definition of a PowerShell global variable

Tags: powershell, global-variables

I'm extremely new to PowerShell (and programming in general - I have no real prior experience though I've done light scripting in the past).  I've been given the opportunity/goal of continuing an automation project that a former employee started and have been given some time to go through the various scripts and framework pieces to try to learn what they do.

The scripts that I'm working with runs in PowerShell and uses some previously created framework files and AutoHotKey files to interact with the User Interface of our software.  In one of the test scripts he has a global variable that gets called, but it isn't defined in that script.  I've been through as many of the framework files as I can find and I cannot locate where this global variable gets set or defined.

I've attempted to use Get-Variable commands in PowerShell but I'm not sure that I'm using it correctly.  I'm not even sure that command would show me where the variable is defined even if I did know how to make it work.

I've also looked around on a number of questions here, but probably due to my lack of experience with programming I don't understand where to go.

This is the specific block of code and I'm looking for the file that sets $global:DESKTOP_OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME.

```
{
        $keys = @("{Home}", $global:DESKTOP_OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME)
        Invoke-SSTIAInteractionPattern -Name "send-keys" -Parameter ($keys) -Delay 2
    },
```

I can paste more of the code here if I need to.

He set this up so we could define an output folder on the desktop of the test machine to save the generated files into.  Instead it is spitting all the files out onto the desktop (thousands of files).  I'm not sure where he sets the output location, which appears to be that specific variable, so I'm hoping there is a way in PowerShell to find that location or file.

Comment: This is not really the solution, but `Agent Ransack` is a software that allows you to look for strings contained in all files of a folder/subfolder. Maybe this could help you find the declaration of your variable.

Comment: if you use VSCode you can use the builtin search to search every file in the  dir tree. i _think_ it uses `ripgrep` as the search util ... so you could install that or some other fairly fast text file search util.

Comment: Does anyone know whether an FR exists for this at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues ?

Answer (score 0):

With [Get-Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable?view=powershell-6) you are able to get variables that are already specified in the  context. And as much as I know you are not able to see, where the variable was set. So I would suggest you take a look in all scripts to find the position inside the code, where the variable is declared. You could use other tools (like "Total Commander 64 bit") to search inside the files or might this snippet:

```
foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path ($FolderPath + '\*.ps1') -File -Recurse))
{
    foreach ($Line in (Get-Content -Path $File.FullName))
    {
        if ($Line -like '*DESKTOP_OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME*')
        {
            Out-Host -InputObject $File.FullName
        }
    }
}
```